# Why does '////'.split('/') produce []?

Tags: ruby

The code `'////'.split('/')` results in `[]`. While I expected it to be `['', '', '', '', '']`. If this is a feature of ruby, why is it designed like so?

Comment: +1.. for asking a good question... :)

Comment: While the question is interesting, it is not in the best form that could have been asked. Your question may mislead the reader that four consecutive  slashes are significant for this effect, but it is not. You will get the same result with shorter slash sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This design provides a convenience for parsing strings with trailing delimiters. For example:

`'1␣2␣3␣␣'.split('␣')` will now give `['1', '2', '3']` rather than `['1', '2', '3', '', '']`.

This feature is just for simplification of workflow.

However, I don't like this feature because it breaks the purity of this method. To achieve the effect above, you just need an extra `rstrip('␣')` between `'1␣2␣3␣␣'` and `split('␣')`.

Answer (score 17):

You can't split string of delimiters by delimiter.

You should pass limit as second parameter to split function to achieve this behaviour

```
'////'.split('/',-1)
=> 
["", "", "", "", ""]
```

If the limit parameter is omitted, trailing null fields are suppressed. If limit is a positive number, at most that number of fields will be returned (if limit is 1, the entire string is returned as the only entry in an array). If negative, there is no limit to the number of fields returned, and trailing null fields are not suppressed

Comment: *+1*..I did... :) But you could add lines from [doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-split) like - **If the limit parameter is omitted, trailing null fields are suppressed**. If limit is a positive number, at most that number of fields will be returned (if limit is 1, the entire string is returned as the only entry in an array). **If negative, there is no limit to the number of fields returned, and trailing null fields are not suppressed.**

Answer (score 10):

Investigation of behaviour of `split` method show that it is result of optimization, it simply crops empty array elements after last match as it is shewn below:

```
'////'.split('/')
=> []

'//a//'.split('/')
=> ["", "", "a"]
```